# application.visble=true brings through new blank workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, visible

As above, I use a `application.visible = False` and `application.visible = true` at the end of my code and once the code has ran and my instance is visible, blank workbooks appear. Does anyone know what causes this?

I have also tried this on a new workbook without any other code than the below and the issue still occurs.

```
Sub TEST()
    Application.Visible = False
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel doesn't create 'ghost' workbooks unless you have created them in your code and did not remove them properly. If your above code is sufficient to reproduce the problem, I would look into upgrading your video hardware/software/driver.

Comment: I ran this, even with 3 hidden workbooks and they were still hidden when the application became visible again - so the problem must lie with some other code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try making just the workbook visible instead of the application:

```
Sub Test()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

This works great when you need to make a background instance visible, but if your macro is run in the foreground, it will leave the blank application open.